# Каганець чи нічна лампа?

Tags: вибір-слова

> [В Академічному тлумачному словнику (1970—1980)](http://sum.in.ua/s/kaghanecj)

наводиться таке значення слова:

> КАГАНЕ́ЦЬ, нця, чол.
>
> 1. Невеличкий світильник, що складається з ґнота та посуду, у який наливається олія, лій чи гас. В хаті каганець ледве-ледве світив (Марко Вовчок, I, 1955, 267); Тихо, наче гніт у каганці, зотлівало його старе життя (Панас Мирний, IV, 1955, 30); На припічку тріскотів лойовий каганець (Леонід Смілянський, Крила, 1954, 51).

[Російсько-українські словники](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) наводять лише каганець як відповідник слову *"ночник"*

А як назвати нічну електричну лампу? Чи є в українській мові усталене слово?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Згідно до СУМу, в українській мові також може вживатися слово ["нічник"](http://sum.in.ua/s/nichnyk).
Також, бачимо варіант нічник в [статті Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA) у розділі "Поширені види світильників".

Comment: І навіть нічничок http://sum.in.ua/s/nichnychok